# Why does my AWS ECS task require docker api 1.18?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

I'm having difficulty creating my cloud formation stack because I'm running into an error when I try and run my tasks. The error arises because the docker api version of the instance is 1.19 and the task definition states that it requires either docker api version 1.17 or 1.18. However I never specified that those versions should be required and I have no idea where these requirements are coming from.

This is my task definition:

```
"uiTaskDefinition" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition",
    "Properties" : {
        "ContainerDefinitions" : [{
            "Name" : "ui",
            "Memory" : "512",
            "PortMappings" : [
                {
                    "HostPort" : "8085",
                    "ContainerPort" : "8080"
                }
            ],
            "Image" : {"Fn::Join" : ["", ["", {"Ref" : "DockerImageRepository"}, ":example_", "ui"]]},
            "Command" : [
                "example.jar"
            ],
            "Essential" : "true",
            "EntryPoint" : [
                "/bin/bash",
                "/cts/runservice.sh"
            ],
            "MountPoints" : [{
                "ContainerPath" : "/logs/",
                "SourceVolume" : "logs"
            }],
            "Cpu" : "128"
        }],
        "Volumes" : [{
            "Name" : "logs",
            "Host" : {
                "SourcePath" : "/var/log/example"
            }
        }]
    }
},
```

But, this is what the AWS console says the task definition is (see the "requiredAttributes" at the top):

```
{
    "requiresAttributes":[
        {
            "value":null,
            "name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
        },
        {
            "value":null,
            "name":"com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        }
    ],
    "taskDefinitionArn":"arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:example:task-definition/example-uiTaskDefinition:1",
    "status":"ACTIVE",
    "revision":1,
    "containerDefinitions":[
        {
            "volumesFrom":[

            ],
            "memory":512,
            "extraHosts":[

            ],
            "dnsServers":[

            ],
            "disableNetworking":null,
            "dnsSearchDomains":[

            ],
            "portMappings":[
                {
                    "hostPort":xxxx,
                    "containerPort":xxxx,
                    "protocol":"tcp"
                }
            ],
            "hostname":null,
            "essential":true,
            "entryPoint":[
                "/bin/bash",
                "/cts/runservice.sh"
            ],
            "mountPoints":[
                {
                    "containerPath":"/logs/",
                    "sourceVolume":"logs",
                    "readOnly":null
                }
            ],
            "name":"ui",
            "ulimits":[

            ],
            "dockerSecurityOptions":[

            ],
            "environment":[

            ],
            "links":[

            ],
            "workingDirectory":null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem":null,
            "image":"example:example_ui",
            "command":[
                "/example.jar"
            ],
            "user":null,
            "dockerLabels":{

            },
            "logConfiguration":null,
            "cpu":128,
            "privileged":null
        }
    ],
    "volumes":[
        {
            "host":{
                "sourcePath":"/var/log/example"
            },
            "name":"logs"
        }
    ],
    "family":"example"
}
```

So where are these required attributes coming from and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Those versions are coming from this file "api/common.go" can you paste what is there in common.go file?

Comment: unfortunately there's no common.go file to be found. There is a common.env file if you'd like to see the contents of that.

Comment: Yes that will work too

Comment: JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled "

Comment: Ok that common.go should be present in your Docker instance many times the path is "docker/api/common.go"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure why but updating my AMI fixed the issue.
Originally: ami-4fe4852a
Now: ami-8f7687e2